# My cells are duplicating themselves

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am new to swift and I am trying to make this note app. I have split view controller that goes in my first view controller and that view controller connects to a table view controller. Everything works perfectly is just that when I launch the app I have all the notes like I want but when I try to go back to my first view controller and come back to my table view controller, all the notes are duplicated every single time I do it. I tried everything I can try, is there anyone who can help me
my MasterViewController is

```
import UIKit

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Note.loadNotes()  // The problem is here, I think
    noteTable = self.tableView

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(insertNewObject(_:)))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
    if let split = splitViewController
    {
        let controllers = split.viewControllers
        detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
    }
}
```

My loadNotes function is

```
class func loadNotes()
{
    let defaults:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let saveData: [NSDictionary]? = defaults.object(forKey: kAllNotes) as? [NSDictionary]

    if let data:[NSDictionary] = saveData
    {
        for i:Int in 0 ..< data.count
        {
            let n:Note = Note()
            n.setValuesForKeys(data[i] as! [String : Any])
            allNotes.append(n)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `loadNotes` method keeps appending. The first line of `loadNotes` should be:

```
allNotes = [Note]()
```

Then it starts with an empty array and fills it up.

And why is `loadNotes` a static method? That's a bad design. Make `Notes` a normal class and make `loadNotes` an instance method.

On an unrelated note (no pun intended), do not use `UserDefaults` to store app data. Only use it to store little bits of information.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. why do think I should use then instead of UserDefaults, coredata?